# rename image during upload not working with Mysql set

Tags: php

I have the bellow code which I was hoping to change/rename image name on upload to user id so I can avoid file overwrite and insert the name into database sadly after I added rename code the code is not able to upload image or update the database we out showing any error but if I remove the rename code everything was working. 
Can one help me how to solve it or is there any better way I can do it?

```
<?php
$user_id = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$username = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
require("connection.php");
if(@$_POST ['submit']) {
    $file = $_FILES ['file'];
    $name1 = $file ['name'];
    $type = $file ['type'];
    $size = $file ['size'];
    $tmppath = $file ['tmp_name'];
    if($type == 'jpeg' || $type == 'png' || $type == 'jpg') {
        $name1 = $user_id.$type; // rename image
        if($name1!="") {
            if(move_uploaded_file ($tmppath, 'users/'.$name1)) {
                $sql=("INSERT INTO USERS set photo='$name1' WHERE username='$username'");
                mysql_query ($sql) or die ('could not updated:'.mysql_error());
                echo ("Profile picture updated");
            }
        }
    } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, may be help you ...

```
<?php
$user_id = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$username = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
require("connection.php");
if(@$_POST ['submit']) {
$file = $_FILES ['file'];
$name1 = time().$file ['name']; // rename image
$type = $file ['type'];
$size = $file ['size'];
$tmppath = $file ['tmp_name'];
if($type == 'image/jpeg' || $type == 'image/png' || $type == 'image/jpg') {
    if($name1!="") {
        if(move_uploaded_file ($tmppath, 'users/'.$name1)) {
            $sql=("INSERT INTO USERS set photo='$name1' WHERE username='$username'");
            mysql_query ($sql) or die ('could not updated:'.mysql_error());
            echo ("Profile picture updated");
        }
    }
} 
}}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all change 
`$name1 = $user_id.$type;`

to

`$name1 = $user_id.".".$type;`
And second of all clean up you sql.

Also. file_type is image/jpeg so that's why it doesn't work. It never goes past your if.

Create a switch to check the filetype or just take the last 3 characters of the file.

Comment: What do you mean by "clean up your sql"?

Comment: @Paul I changed but function.move-uploaded-file no such file

Comment: I disagree, it is perfectly acceptable to pass variables into SQL strings like this.

Comment: Make sure that you have that directory there and do a var dump to see what is your $name1 and check is it is what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to reorganise your `$_FILES` into an array you can understand and easily work with.

*Shameless plug*

https://gist.github.com/lukeoliff/5531772#file-quickrearrangefiles-php

```
<?php
  function rearrangeFiles($arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $all){
      foreach($all as $i => $val){
        $new[$i][$key] = $val;
      }
    }
    return $new;
  }
```

Used as such:

```
<?php
  $user_id = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  $username = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

  require("connection.php");

  if(!empty($_POST) && !empty($_FILES)) {
    $files = rearrangeFiles($_FILES)
    foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
      $name    = $file['name'];
      $type    = $file['type'];
      $size    = $file['size'];
      $tmppath = $file['tmp_name'];
      if($type == 'jpeg' || $type == 'png' || $type == 'jpg') {
        $name = time() . '_' . $user_id.'_'.$name.'.'.$type; // TIMESTAMP, USERID and FILENAME RENAME
        if(!empty($name)) {
          if(move_uploaded_file($tmppath, 'users/'.$name)) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (photo,username) values ('$name','$username')";
            mysql_query($sql) or die('could not updated:'.mysql_error());
            $successes[] = $file['name'] . " picture saved as " . $name;
          }
        }
      } 
    }
    if (!empty($successes)) {
      echo implode('. ',$successes);
    }
  }
```

Further improved by inserting into database in a single query :) Also you really need to move from mysql_ functions to mysqli_ or PDO:: functions as per php.net http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php depreciating mysql_ functions soon.

Answer (score -1):

you can use that one concept, but edit this as your requirement.

```
<?php
if ($_FILES['imagepath']['name'] != "")
{
    $uploaddir = 'images/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['imagepath']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagepath']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
    {
    $rename = $_FILES['imagepath']['name'];
                $rename = rand(0,1500000000).$rename;
                $filename = strtolower(($rename));
                if (file_exists(($uploaddir.$_FILES['imagepath']['name'])))
                    rename(($uploaddir.$_FILES['imagepath']['name']), ($uploaddir.$filename));
    echo $_FILES['imagepath']['name']."&nbsp;with name&nbsp;".$filename."&nbsp;file uploaded successfully";
    }
}
?>
```